# ObjectOutputStream objects sometimes flush automatically. How can I know exactly when to rely on this behavior and when to flush manually?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I've noticed that sometimes, a thread calling a write method on an ObjectOutputStream object, like `writeUTF()`, to send a value via a socket will flush the data automatically, so that there is no need for me to call `flush()` on the object. The thread at the other end of the communication line receives the data just fine. This has worked even when the sender thread writes on the stream object many hundreds of times under a loop.

Other times, my threads are deadlocked because the sender threads are not sending the data. This problem is fixed when I manually call a `flush()` method immediately after invoking, for example, `writeUTF()`.

I doubt that this is random. I think there must be some specific circumstance under which threads writing to a stream flush the data automatically. I would like to know what those circumstances are, if any.

Comment: I think there are too many layers of abstraction here. Could be the stream operation, could be the operating system... I simply would not rely on any automatisms here.

Comment: *Any* buffered output stream is flushed automatically when the output buffer fills. Doesn't change anything. You flush when you need to flush. No need for any kind of micro-optimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implementation dependent and may change depending on platform, version, and build of Java.  Your best bet is to call flush() whenever you might need to.  If there is no data to be flushed, a call to flush() is extremely fast, so this will not significantly slow down your program.